# mysql - Select distinct rows from 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Table 1(pending_order)
```

[image: Link]

```
Table 2(user)
```

[image: link]

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM user,pending_order WHERE user.id= pending_order.user_id
```

Expected o/p:
Only 2 rows as there are 2 pending orders from user 1,2. But I am getting all the rows of `pending_order` table combined with `user` table.

Comment: Can the downvoter at least comment why my question was downvoted?

Comment: Your data has four pending orders for those two ids.  Why do you think only two rows should be returned?

Comment: At the php side, In the admin panel, I would like to the display a table which shows all the pending orders from x users.
When I click on say, user 2, It would display all the pending orders from user 2.
Hence, for the first part where I would like to display only the distinct pending orders. Hope I am making sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be more correct to use `Inner Join` in this case:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.*
FROM user Inner Join pending_order
On user.id = pending_order.user_id
```

`Join` types (`inner`/`full`/`right`..) is about cases that you want to combine results from more then one related tables in your single query.

You can read more about it here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm

Comment: Doesn't work. Also, I updated the first table's photo. I guess, the earlier photo might not have given you enough idea about the problem.

Comment: @ReubenRodriguez in this case you probably want to display only the users (that ordered something) data, and not the orders. To do this, user users.* in the select, and the distinct will do the work for you. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should work.  But I would write it as:

```
SELECT u.*, po.*
FROM user u JOIN
     pending_order po
     ON u.id = po.user_id;
```

This should return only user 2, who has a pending order.

If you want only users who have pending orders, use `exists:

```
select u.*
from user u
where exists (select 1
              from pending_order po
              where u.id = po.user_id
             );
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Also, I updated the first table's photo. I guess, the earlier photo might not have given you enough idea about the problem.